# How do i fix this "cannot load such file -- /home/max/app_project/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, devise, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I don't want users to enter their current password when editing their profile. But after setting that up, this is the error i get when i go to the **Edit Profile** page **localhost:3000/profile**
[This is an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW0fG.jpg)

```
cannot load such file -- /home/max/app_project/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
```

This is what i have in my **registrations_controller.rb** and **routes.rb**

```
app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    protected
        def update_resource(resource, params)
            resource.update_without_password(params)
        end
end



==============================================================================================


config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'

  devise_for :users,
              path: '',
              path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', edit: 'profile', sign_up: 'registration'},
              controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations'}

  resources :users, only: [:show]
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  #Provides better error page for Rails and other Rack apss.
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.5', '>= 2.5.1'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.4.1'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'toastr-rails'

gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.9'

gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 5.0'
```

How do i fix this?

**Running**

Devise 4.7.1

Ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]

Rails 6.0.2.1

Windows 10 1909 Build 18363.535

Comment: Options: the file is actually not where it is expected (or does not contain the correct class --check for typos), or the file is not valid ruby and thus does not load?

Comment: Please which file?

Comment: `registrations_controller.rb`

Comment: here I will do following command `cat /home/max/app_project/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb` if I got controller code than it is ok, otherwise it is not here, so make this file and put content as you mention in your question.

Comment: Where is it expected to be?

Comment: @KamalPanhwar That's exactly what i have.

Comment: Well that all looks good and error is complete surprise, as there is possibility any error code, I also check with devise reference and all looks good. just make in controller starts with `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` and ends after update_resource method and has no error.

Comment: This error doesn't make any sense to me. As I see it, there are two possibilities: (1) There is a spelling mistake somewhere which you're not replicating in this StackOverflow post, or (2) the server is in a weird state; if you restart it then things will work again.

Comment: For example, this error could be caused by the silly mistake: *you forgot to save the file??*

Comment: I saved the file. I've gone through it several times to find typos but found nothing.

Comment: @TomLord You can see in the image i posted

Comment: @Richard Did your restart the server? The error makes no sense to me. It's saying a file doesn't exist, but you insist it does exist... The only other thing I see as a bit odd is that your question is tagged as `Windows`, but `/home/max/app_project/` doesn't look like a Windows file path... Is there some other unusual setup (e.g. docker) being used that you didn't mention?

Comment: @TomLord I'm using WSL on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I also program on Windows 10 using ubuntu bash. I don't know why but whenever I have a "file not found" related problem I run `chmod -R 755 appfolder` and, most of the time, the problem is solved.